# CheckBoxPreference title long text doesn't start second line

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I have PreferenceScreen contain CheckBoxPreference which referd in manifest to PreferencesTheme , its title text is long so it appear in single line and words cut at end of line , im try to force screen to continue the text in second line by using :

```
<item name="android:lines">2</item>
```

in prefs_style.xml but it doesnt work .

any help to solve that will be appreciated , thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and created a custom layout for my `CheckBoxPreference` by adding  `android:layout`:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
   android:defaultValue="true"
   android:key="@string/pref_key"
   android:summary="@string/pref_summary"
   android:title="@string/pref_title"
   android:layout="@layout/preference_layout"/>
```

With a custom layout you can make the Preference look however you would like. [Here is an example of what the internal layout looks like](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c8834722d5591d1381dc199f04a544a6b11b74bd/core/res/res/layout/preference_holo.xml).  If you remove the `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:ellipsize="marquee"` from that layout you should get the experience you want.

Comment: i try it but still one thing i cant customize the divider betwwen checkboxs

Comment: @JustinMorris Can you help? when i put custom layout to CheckBoxPreference, checkbox ha been hidden.